# Haskell "threeRoundFight" overwrite variables by nesting lambdas

Tags: haskell

From Will Kurt "Get Programming in Haskell" Unit 1 Ch.10 extension assignment:

> Write a threeRoundFight function that takes two robots and has them
> fight for three rounds, returning the winner. To avoid having so many
> different variables for robot state, use a series of nested lambda
> functions so you can just overwrite robotA and robotB.

I have:

```
-- a robot object
robot (name, attack, hp) = (\message -> message (name, attack, hp))

--getters, setters and helpers

--accessors helpers, func that return first of tuple
name (n,_,_) = n 
attack (_,a,_) = a 
hp (_,_,hp) = hp
--accessors 10.10, func accepts a lambda containing tuple
--then calls lambda that calls func that returns member of tuple
getName aRobot = aRobot name
getAttack aRobot = aRobot attack
getHP aRobot = aRobot hp

--setters
setName aRobot newName = aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (newName, a, h))
setAttack aRobot newAttack = aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (n, newAttack, h))
setHP aRobot newHP = aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (n, a, newHP))

--take damage, returns new robot
damage aRobot attackDamage = 
    aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (n,a,h-attackDamage))

fight attacker defender = damage defender attackDamage --defender takes damage
    where attackDamage = if getHP attacker > 0  --if attacker alive
                            then getAttack attacker --get attack val
                         else 0 --cannot attack
```

from which I am trying to write a function called threeRoundFight where each robot attacks three times.

I was looking at this:  https://gist.github.com/mikekeke/c6c2cd609acbca81da1ff9be547d3d2d

Mainly the nesting that person used that looks like:

```
threeRoundFight r1 r2 = 
    (\r1 r2 -> 
        (\r1 r2 -> 
            (\r1 r2 -> 
                (\r1 r2 -> 
                    (\r1 r2 -> 
                        (\r1 r2 -> fight r2 r1)
                    r1 (fight r1 r2))
                (fight r2 r1) r2) 
            r1 (fight r1 r2)) 
        (fight r2 r1) r2) 
     r1 (fight r1 r2) 
    ) r1 r2
```

Tried to break it down but this does not work (I inserted line numbers):

```
threeRoundFight a b = 
1    (\a b ->
2        (\a b -> fight b a)
3        a (fight a b)  --Occurs check, cannot construct the infinite type
4    ) a b
```

Can somebody show me how to fix what I have so each robot gets one attack?  I looked back at Ch.3 "overwrite variables" but still don't get this as it doesn't really explain how the nesting works, do the lambdas get called outside->in?  Then the very last `a b` gets assigned to the line 1 `a b` then line `a (fight a b)` gets called.  That leaves the same `a` and an updated/new `b` which are now assigned to `(\a b -> fight b a)`.  Thus both `a` and `b` should have lower HP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a reasonably experienced Haskell programmer, and I find this exercise bizarre (having seen other questions about it before). I understand the part about making a robot be a 3-tuple buried in some message-passing / continuation stuff - it's pretty unusual style for normal programming, but teaches useful techniques. But this thing about using 6 nested lambdas so that you can reuse binding names is awful, and reading the working solution you've linked to I can't at all tell whether it's correct.

I would suggest just using some different techniques. The main problem is that you have two variables that need to be updated and passed to the same function in different orders. So, I would simplify by writing a `oneRound` function that keeps the robots in the *same* order but has them each attack once. Then, just call that three times.

```
oneRound (a, b) = (\damagedb -> (fight damagedb a, damagedb)) (fight a b)

threeRoundFight a b = oneRound (oneRound (oneRound (a, b)))
```

Even this is not the style I would normally write in, but it's at least somewhat reasonable, and seems to teach the same things the exercise was getting at.

However, it turns out my solution needs GHC extensions to typecheck. Now I understand why this exercise, unlike most real Haskell code, omits the type annotations. You can't write the proper types without some fairly advanced concepts. Here is what I had to do to get my code to actually compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

type Robot = forall r. ((String, Int, Int) -> r) -> r

-- a robot object
robot (name, attack, hp) = (\message -> message (name, attack, hp))

--getters, setters and helpers

--accessors helpers, func that return first of tuple
name (n,_,_) = n
attack (_,a,_) = a
hp (_,_,hp) = hp
--accessors 10.10, func accepts a lambda containing tuple
--then calls lambda that calls func that returns member of tuple
getName aRobot = aRobot name
getAttack aRobot = aRobot attack
getHP aRobot = aRobot hp

--setters
setName aRobot newName = aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (newName, a, h))
setAttack aRobot newAttack = aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (n, newAttack, h))
setHP aRobot newHP = aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (n, a, newHP))

--take damage, returns new robot
damage aRobot attackDamage =
    aRobot (\(n,a,h) -> robot (n,a,h-attackDamage))

fight attacker defender = damage defender attackDamage --defender takes damage
    where attackDamage = if getHP attacker > 0  --if attacker alive
                            then getAttack attacker --get attack val
                         else 0 --cannot attack

oneRound :: (Robot, Robot) -> (Robot, Robot)
oneRound (a, b) = let damagedb = fight a b
                  in (fight damagedb a, damagedb)

threeRoundFight :: Robot -> Robot -> (Robot, Robot)
threeRoundFight a b = oneRound (oneRound (oneRound (a, b)))
```

Your question code remains unmodified; I've added two extensions at the top, and a definition of the proper type of Robot. This is needed to allow us to give a proper type to `oneRound` and `threeRoundFight`, which I've added. I've also changed my lambda to a let; this is a more natural style, and also needed to allow the polymorphic binding.

Rest assured that in normal Haskell code we can write elegant functions like `threeRoundFight` without having to use weird types - it is only the unusual design of the Robot type used in this exercise that makes this at all difficult.

You asked how I would normally write this. I'd leave `oneRound` as is (now that it's using a let instead of a lamdba), but `threeRoundFight` would use abstraction instead of repetition:

```
threeRoundFight :: Robot -> Robot -> (Robot, Robot)
threeRoundFight a b = iterate oneRound (a, b) !! 3
```

Comment: I received similar feedback for another question on closures in this book so I guess the author is trying to teach some concepts however unorthodox.  But this is great to get advice from a real Haskell developer and I'll keep in mind what you said for other exercises.  Your solution is so elegant, I can't wait to learn an even better style you refer to.

Comment: Also, if you know of a "better" book please recommend it.  I like this book so far but would not mind having a second reference textbook.

Comment: I get your logic but getting red squigglies under the last `a` in `oneRound` and two right hand side nested `(oneRound (oneRound (a, b)))` in `fightThreeRounds`

Comment: I've clarified the answer

Comment: The next chapter introduces types so I guess my first instinct, before asking here, to move on and come back later to this question was right.  But I always second guess myself when learning something new.